# nginx/django file download permission

Tags: django, nginx

i have a django website running on ubuntu nginx where a user can upload image and another user can download the image.
Problem is when i upload image from frontend then another user can view the image but can't download the original image and when i upload the image from backend its downloadable. 
i need to change file permission every time to download the image

nginx.conf:

```
 user www-data;
 worker_processes auto;
 pid /run/nginx.pid;
 include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

  events {
      worker_connections 768;
      # multi_accept on;
   }

  http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;        
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;



    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

default settings:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 159.65.156.40;
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static {
    root /home/tboss/liveimage;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
 }
location /media/ {
    root /home/tboss/liveimage;
 }
 location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/tboss/liveimage/liveimage.sock;
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand "another user can view the image but can't download the original image". What does "view the image" mean? If I view an image in a browser, it means it can be downloaded otherwise how would I view it?

Comment: i mean image is downloadable when i change the file permission from server

Comment: maybe your django server (uwsgi? gunicorn?) isn't running with the same user as your nginx server. But I still don't understand how the user can "view the image" but not "download it". What's the difference?

Comment: see the edits image are loading on browser but when i click on download button its download the html file but when i change the file permission its downloadble

Comment: maybe you are right i have user root and tboss

Comment: but what you describe is not possible. If the browser can download the image in `<img src="/path/to/your/image.png">` then the user can also download it.

Comment: its downloading the html document not the image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205864/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-afk).